# Change default URL param name when using Route::resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

When using `Route::resource()`, Laravel of course 'chooses' somethings for you, such as route names and methods.

I know how to override, for example, the allowed routes/methods:

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController', array('only' => array('index', 'show')));
```

But I now need to override the URL param name that Laravel sets for the `user` routes. By default, in the example above, it will be `user`. But, I want it to be `user_id`.

Does Laravel provide a way to set this, when using `Route::resource`?

So that, for example, I would end up with the route:

`mydomain.com/users/{user_id}`

rather than:

`mydomain.com/users/{user}`

Thanks

Comment: Why the down vote please?

Comment: i didn't down vote but someone probably did because of the lack of research ... this is directly in the laravel docs for resource routing; so you didn't do the appropriate research (checking the docs) ... my guess for their thinking

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Yes, Laravel does provide a way to override this when using `Route::resource()`.

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController')->parameters([
    'users' => 'user_id'
]);
```

The key of the element in the array in the argument to 'parameters' is the same as what you enter as the first argument of the 'resource' method (not the 'singular' version or something)